# Does the sendSignInLinkToEmail function work with a firebase emulator?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

Does the sendSignInLinkToEmail function work with a firebase emulator?
I tried the following code.
Firebase hosting sends an email, but firebase emulator doesn't.
(create and login are working with emulator.)
If anyone knows, please let me know.

"firebase": "^8.1.1"

"docker": "v19.03.13"

"node(in docker)": "14-alpine"

"vue(in docker)": "^2.6.11"

**sourceCode firebase.js(initialize)**

```
import fbapp from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"
const config = {
 apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_FIB_API_KEY,
 authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_FIB_AUTHDOMAIN,
 databaseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_FIB_FIRESTORE_URL,
 projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIB_PROJECT_ID,
 storageBucket: process.env.VUE_APP_FIB_STRG_BUCKET,
 messagingSenderId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIB_MSG_ID,
 corsConfiguration: [{ maxAgeSeconds: 3600 }],
 measurementId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIB_MEASUREMENT_ID,
 appId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIB_APP_ID
 }
const firebase = fbapp.initializeApp(config);

export default {
  initAuth() {
    firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099/')
  return auth;
}
```

**sourceCode authMail.vue**

```
 import Firebase from '@/firebase';
 const fb_auth = Firebase.initAuth();
 // ~~ ~~ //
 methods: {
 async sendAuthMail(email){
  const actionCodeSettings = {
    url: process.env.VUE_APP_URL + '/signup/authorize' + redirect_param,
    handleCodeInApp: true
  }

  fb_auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
    .then(function() {
      window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email);
      return true
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      return error
  });
```

},

Answer (score 8):

As the documentation on [emulated email, email link and anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#emulated_email_email_link_and_anonymous_authentication) says:

> For testing email verification/sign-in with email link flows, the emulator prints a URL to the terminal at which firebase emulators:start was executed.

> i  To verify the email address customer@ex.com, follow this link:
> `http://localhost:9099/emulator/action?mode=verifyEmail&lang=en&oobCode=XYZ123&apiKey=fake-api-key`

> Paste the link into your browser to simulate the verification event, and check whether verification succeeded.
>
> ```
> {
>   "authEmulator": {
>     "success": "The email has been successfully verified.",
>     "email": "customer@example.com"
>   }
> }
> ```

So the emulator doesn't send email, and you need to check the console output of the emulator for the link to verify it and sign in.

Comment: For some reason when I was trying to get `sendSignInLinkToEmail` to work, I was under the impression that it was suppose to output to the browser console instead of the terminal with the emulators command. (Placing this comment here to help anyone who might be looking at the wrong terminal )