# User isn't authenticated after completing sign in with email link form firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js13

I have a sign in form where user can auth with email link form firebase. After that in gmail user clicks on link and navigates to some route where he should be authenticated but it doesn't happen. Is my sendSignInLinkToEmail logic correct? Also i made sure that i have allowed sign in with email link.

Form

```
export const SignIn = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, values.email, actionCodeSettings)
          .then(() => {
            window.localStorage.setItem("emailForSignIn", values.email);
            setAlertLabel("A sign-in link has been sent to your email");
          })
          .catch(() =>
            setAlertLabel(
              "Something went wrong while sending the sign-in link. Please try again later"
            )
          );
        setSubmitting(false);
      }}
    >
      {({ values, handleSubmit, handleChange }) => {
        return (
         ...
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

Config

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
  url: "http://localhost:3000",
  handleCodeInApp: true,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

please confirm the following

> url: The deep link to embed and any additional state to be passed
> along. The link's domain has to be added in the Firebase Console list
> of authorized domains, which can be found by going to the Sign-in
> method tab (Authentication -> Settings).

also while testing you might want to look at [does-the-sendsigninlinktoemail-function-work-with-a-firebase-emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65016270/does-the-sendsigninlinktoemail-function-work-with-a-firebase-emulator)

Comment: Hi, no changes. In my console I get Missing or insufficient permission probably due to failed auth